# Linear congruence in multiple variables and multiple residue systems

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For problems involving one variable and $m_{i}, m_{j}$ we can solve systems of the form

$
x \equiv b_{i} \quad (\text{mod }  m_{i}) \quad i=1,...k
$

using there Chinese remainder theorem directly or discarding equations implied by the others (or find contradictions), then using CRT.

With $m_{i} = m_{j}$, for all $i,j$ it is sometimes possible to solve

$\sum a_{ij} x_{j} \equiv  b_{i}$ for i=1,...,k

where $x_{j}$ denotes the fact that we have multiple variables.

My question pertains to the situation where the latter scenario is modified to allow the $m_{i}$ to vary. For example

$
x-y \equiv 2 \quad (\text{mod }  6) \text{,}\quad x+y \equiv 0 \quad (\text{mod }  8)
$

This has solutions (e.g. x=0, y=16, x=1, y=23, ...) but I have a hard time seeing how to approach it in a structured way since we are now working over two residue systems. Is there a general theory for these problems?